# MacOS Big Slur and VMware Fusion NAT not working

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

MacOS Big and VMware Fusion 12, NAT networking not working anyone run into similar issues before?

No internet/Network access with VPN or without VPN.

Any help is massively appreciated.

VM operating system: Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The issue has been fixed in VMWare Fusion 12.2.0 VPN

Answer (score 3):

Below is the workaround for this issue. It's a bummer it would not work out of the box.

### Host Machine with no VPN:

1. Update the DNS to `1.1.1.1` or `8.8.8.8` within your VM (In my case Ubuntu)

[image]

2. Disable and enable the network again. (It should take ~10 sec to show the network connectivity.)
3. Done! You should have internet now.

### **If you're on a VPN your Host machine:**

**In your Host MacOS BigSur**

1. Add the last two lines below into file /private/etc/pf.conf (symlink of /etc/pf.conf). The location these are added in the file is important and must be at the beginning along with the other nat

```
vi /private/etc/pf.conf
```

```
#
# com.apple anchor point
#
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"

nat-anchor "com.apple.internet-sharing/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple.internet-sharing/*"
```

and then reloaded the pf.

```
sudo pfctl -d
sudo pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf
```

2. List all the DNS servers on your MacOS and make a note of the DNS IP addresses. (Please note you might have some duplicate IP addresses, just ignore them.)

```
% scutil --dns | grep 'nameserver\[[0-9]*\]'
```

```
  nameserver[0] : 10.32.111.250
  nameserver[1] : 10.21.112.250
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.0.1
  ...
  ...
```

**In your VM:**

3. In your VM, update all the DNS entries in Network Settings:

[image]

or alternatively, you can add them in your `/etc/resolve.conf`

```
...
nameserver 10.32.111.250
nameserver 10.21.112.250
...
```

4. Disable and enable the network.
5. Done! you should be able to access the VPN sites.

> If it still doesn't work disable IPV6. Or you may have to do similar settings for IPV6 as well.